# sed or awk with variable and special charachters

Tags: awk, sed

I want to use awk or sed to substitute 1 line in my file:

my file content is:

```
server.modules += ( "mod_redirect" )

$SERVER["socket"] == ":8080" {
    $HTTP["host"] =~ "(.*)" {
        url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "https://someurl.com/unauthorised" )
    }
}
```

I want to change the line containing `url.redirect`
The new line is in variable and containing some special charachter will be somthing like this `url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "http://newurl.com/newpath" )`

so I used the following sed comand:

```
sed "/url\.redirect =/s/.*/$newline/" 10-redirect.conf
```

But I got error related to the special characters inside the `newline` variable.

the newline is an argument of my shell function so I can not change it and add some skip characters inside.

How to use variables with special charachters in `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: Replace the newline in `$newline` for `\\n`. Then run `sed`. Or at best use a temporary file and use `r` and `d` sed commands.

Comment: try `sed '/url\.redirect =/c'"$newline"` and if that fails, try `echo "$newline" | sed -e '/url\.redirect =/ {r /dev/stdin' -e 'd}'`

Comment: @KamilCuk there is no `\n` in the `$newline`

Comment: Replace special characters in `$newline` for something sed understand. For example replace the newline character inside `newline` variable for 2 characters: slash \ and character `n`.

Comment: @Sundeep. the first solution is good. But it removes all the spaces of the beginning of the line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `GNU sed` and `c` command (which replaces the matched lines with the string provided). If there are spaces at the start of string, prefix `\` to preserve them

```
sed '/url\.redirect =/c\'"$newline"
```

However, `c` command will still allow escape sequences, for example:

```
$ s='   rat\tdog\nwolf'
$ seq 3 | sed '2c\'"$s"
1
   rat  dog
wolf
3
```

To add contents literally and robustly, use `r` command

```
echo "$newline" | sed -e '/url\.redirect =/ {r /dev/stdin' -e 'd}'
```

Here's `r` command in action

```
$ s='   rat\tdog\nwolf'
$ echo "$s" | sed -e '2 {r /dev/stdin' -e 'd}' <(seq 3)
1
   rat\tdog\nwolf
3
```

Comment: Another variation is to use Bashs here-string `sed -e '/url\.redirect/r /dev/stdin' -e '//d' <<<"$newline" file` or if more than one line is to be replaced use a here-document piped via cat into the same mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following. This should put same spaces in front of new value what were present before.

```
newline='url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "https://example.com/authorised" )'
awk -v line="$newline" '
/url.redirect =/{
  match($0,/^ +/)
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) line
  next
}
1
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error in `sed` because it is using a regex and your replacement string may contain meta-characters such as `&` or `/` (delimiters) etc.

This `awk` would be safer to use due to non-regex approach:

```
newline='url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "https://example.com/authorised" )'

awk -i inplace -v line="$newline" 'index($0, "url.redirect =") {
   sub(/[^[:blank:]].*/, "")
   $0 = $0 line
} 1' file
```

```
server.modules += ( "mod_redirect" )

$SERVER["socket"] == ":8080" {
    $HTTP["host"] =~ "(.*)" {
    url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "https://example.com/authorised" )
    }
}
```

Note that using `ENVIRON` would allow all the shell special characters to 
awk:

```
export newline

awk -i inplace 'index($0, "url.redirect =") {
   sub(/[^[:blank:]].*/, "")
   $0 = $0 ENVIRON["newline"]
} 1' file
```

Comment: Your solution is good. I am just getting extra tab at the beggining of the file. How to remove it ?

Comment: I had `"\t"` at the start for indentation, removed it now. Please try again.

Comment: thank you.
Could you please add more answer. In fcat I want to replace directly the file like `sed -i`. how to make it with awk ?

Comment: Just add `-i inplace` after awk to save changes inline